# Any good resource (non-people) management libraries?

Tags: testing, resources, automated-tests

As our automated test infrastructure grows, we have a need to automatically manage the test resources (servers, etc). Not manage updates to the systems but have an automatic (programmatic) way to reserve resources for use in the automated test runs and release resources when finished. I need to be able to to add items to the system, store meta data about them, reserve them, and release the resources when finished. Are there any such existing systems that manage resources this way that could be integrated with other programs? Target languages to interface with such as system are Java, or C# but if something else good exists in another language (or had some way to interface with it from other languages) I'd take a look at it too.

Comment: Any news by any chance? :) Need the same thing over here

Comment: No haven't come across anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is there isn't one and I need to roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Selenium Grid? It allows you requisition a cluster of servers for automated testing.. it even works with Amazon's cloud computing services..
http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: My resource management needs aren't web based, need to manage the servers, other equipment I have.